# Why do I see gif in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, animated-gif

I would like to see the animated gif when I click the button in Chrome as I do in Firefox.

I have tried timeouts but to no avail. This seems so basic. However I am stumped.

Does anyone know how I may achieve this?

```js
$(document).on('click',".opener",function(event){
    $(".ajaxSpinnerImage").show();
    $("button").hide();
    alert("In FF I will now see the gif. In Chrome I won't.");
    $("body").html("Done!");
});
```

```css
.ajaxSpinnerImage{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="opener">Click me to see animated gif</button>
<img src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.16.1/images/loader-large.gif" class="ajaxSpinnerImage" title="Please wait...">
```

Comment: It's because `alert()` blocks the UI thread from updating. If you need the UI to update while showing a notification to the user use a library that creates them from HTML code, not the `alert()` box. They look pretty unprofessional anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I think you have hit nail on head. When I change the alert to setTimeout(function() {$("body").html("Done!");}, 3000); the gif appears in Chrome.